# "Read More" button in HTML auto hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have a look at the script:

```js
document.querySelector('#b1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#c1').style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelector('#b2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#c2').style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px verdana;
}

#c1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 5.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
}

#c2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 5.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
  This is small para
</div>
<button id="b1">Read more</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="c2">
  There's a lot of text in this para. So the para is being very large. Hence, it will show the full text by clicking the "Read more" button! The texts are being repeated, so that para will be large. There's a lot of text in this para. So the para is being very large. Hence, it will show the full text by clicking the "Read more" button! The texts are being repeated, so that para will be large. There's a lot of text in this para. So the para is being very large. Hence, it will show the full text by clicking the "Read more" button! The texts are being repeated, so that para will be large. There's a lot of text in this para. So the para is being very large. Hence, it will show the full text by clicking the "Read more" button! The texts are being repeated, so that para will be large.
</div>
<button id="b2">Read more</button>
```

For the first para, **`#c1`** there's no need of **<kbd>Read more</kbd>**, so how can it be hidden as there is no use...?

**UPDATE 1**

> I have **no** control over the text **length**.

Earlier, the `height` and `width` were set for just an example as *2.6em* and *200px* respectively, therefore I got a **solution**:

> You can iterate over each `div` and check its text content. If it is
>   less than the certain length you can hide its next element, i.e the
>   button. In below code, you can adjust **100** to any value you want.
>
> By [Hari Das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2473505/hari-das), **[Solution DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pso5t76q/9/)**

**Why Hari's solution do not match my question?**

*I am not giving preference to the number of `characters`, I am giving preference to the height of `div`.*

**Why I am giving preference to the height of the div?**

*If I go with Hari's solution:*

*Suppose there are only **3** letters on **each** line till the line **15**, the `div's` **height** will be **long** and the **characters** length will be **less** than **100**, so here Hari's solution will not collapse the para and no button will be shown...*

Comment: why do you need that in the markup in the first place? Can you not have the html without the first readmore  button?

Comment: I think he has no control on the text length. He is asking about how to dinamically adapt

Comment: so what is the min/max length of text beyond which you need the button to show up?

Comment: Hope all the doubts are clear with the new updates to the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over each `div` and check its scrollHeight. If it is less than visible height you can hide its next element, i.e the button.

```js
document.querySelector('#b1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#c1').style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelector('#b2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#c2').style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.display = 'none';
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
    if($(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this)[0].offsetHeight){
      $(this).next().hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px verdana;
}

#c1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 200px;
}

#c2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1">
  This is small para
</div>
<button id="b1">Read more</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="c2">
  There's lot of text in this para. So the para is being very large. Hence, it will show full text on clicking "Read more" button! The texts are being repeated, so that para will be large. There's lot of text in this para. So the para is being very large.
  Hence, it will show full text on clicking "Read more" button! The texts are being repeated, so that para will be large.
</div>
<button id="b2">Read more</button>
```

Comment: Updated code using scrollHeight. Check if that solves your issue.

Comment: The button is hidden, but the text is collapsed. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/pso5t76q/15/). The reason button is hidden is because your script is counting the characters not the height!

Comment: Ok I updated code with dynamic height. Now it should work with all cases.

Comment: I tried this, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pso5t76q/23/) but it's not hiding the button. (This time second one..)

Comment: You have not injected jquery into your code and trying to use $. Inject jquery with the script tag like in my code above.

Comment: No, it's not hiding when I am trying to execute on my server/localhost. [Visit Here](http://jainvidhya.co.in/developer/)

Comment: jquery .height() was not returning correct value. I changed it to .offsetHeight. Check my code again. Now it works.

Comment: That is because your .card-body has a height of 2.6em which is not enough to hold a single line as well. Change your if block with following

if($(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this)[0].offsetHeight || ($(this)[0].scrollHeight > $(this)[0].offsetHeight && ($(this)[0].scrollHeight-$(this)[0].offsetHeight)<25)){
 $(this).next().hide();
 $(this).css("height","auto");
}

Comment: Ok, the code `$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".post-short" ).each(function( index ) {
        if($(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this)[0].offsetHeight){
      $(this).next().hide();
    }
  });` is hiding the whole div, I just want to hide that button..., as in future there will be more buttons on that div...

Comment: You can do it like as $(this).next().find("button").hide();

Comment: But there will be two or more buttons in the future...and if I will use `$(this).next().find("button").hide();`, it will hide all buttons in that div...

Comment: You can assign a specific class name to that button and use that class name in that selector.